# Which Qt class should I use to represent an image on a rectangle?

Tags: c++, image, qt, paint, qt5

I have a self coded rectangle (not using `QRect` for educational purposes), which looks like so:

```
class Block {

private: // also has getters and setters for this stuff
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
    uint m_width;
    uint m_height;
    QColor m_color;

public:
    Block(int x = 0, int y = 0, uint w = 64, uint h = 64);
    Block(const QColor &color, int x = 0, int y = 0, uint w = 64, uint h = 64);

    void paint(QPainter &painter) const
    {
        painter.fillRect(m_x, m_y, m_width, m_height, m_color);
    }
};
```

Now I'd like to add a support for images, so the block can either have a color or an image (if both provided, image will be used).
The problem is, there are too many classes to represent images (`QPixmap`, `QImage`, `QIcon`) and I have no idea which one should I use.
What are the differences, which one is best suited for simply drawing a resource image into a rectangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display the image on screen, use `QPixmap`. If you want to modify image, load or save it to file, use `QImage`.

`QIcon` is based on `QPixmap` and provides ability to choose one of many pixmaps based on requested size and state. `QIcon` is probably not what you want.

From the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpixmap.html#details):

> Qt provides four classes for handling image data: QImage, QPixmap, QBitmap and QPicture. QImage is designed and optimized for I/O, and for direct pixel access and manipulation, while QPixmap is designed and optimized for showing images on screen. QBitmap is only a convenience class that inherits QPixmap, ensuring a depth of 1. Finally, the QPicture class is a paint device that records and replays QPainter commands.
>
> The QIcon class provides scalable icons in different modes and states. A QIcon can generate smaller, larger, active, and disabled pixmaps from the set of pixmaps it is given. Such pixmaps are used by Qt widgets to show an icon representing a particular action.